# System Reserved too full, how to reduce/recreate?

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I wanted to create a system image, but I got the "not enough disk space" error. The target disk is more than big enough, so it must be the source. I followed [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/fix-the-0x80780119-error-when-creating-a-system-image-in-windows-7-and-8/), and deleted the journal from the System Reserved partition, but still only 5% is free from the 100MB.

> fsutil usn deletejournal /N /D Q:

Normally around 70% is free. I want to get there, and the article did not help.

I have a recovery disk, how can I format the System Reserved partition?
Is it safe? Or how else can I reset it?

Comment: How much free space to you have in the other partitions?

Comment: The article you linked itself explains how to do what your asking us to explain how to do.

Comment: You don't want to shrink the partition your asking about you actually want to expand it so it meets the requirements of what you are trying to do ( by having 50MB free on partitions less then 350MB )

Comment: I do not want to expand the partition, I want to remove the unneccessary files.

Comment: They are all necessary if you want to retain your ability to use the WinRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know what used up so much space.
However, I booted from a Linux pendrive, formatted the System Reserved to NTFS, set it active, and then I just used the Windows Install pendrive to repair the boot partition.

I was able to create a system image without a problem now.