# How can I free up space in the System Reserved partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, disk-image, windows-backup

I'm trying to create a system image backup of my Windows 7 64bit syste, however I only have 35MB free in my 100MB System Reserved partition and I need a minimum of 50MB (error code 0x80780119)

I've tried deleting the USN Journal as per [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/fix-the-0x80780119-error-when-creating-a-system-image-in-windows-7-and-8/), however that only frees 2MB. I've also tried resizing the partition with Gparted, but that moves the location of boot sector of my C: drive which is Not A Good Thing.

I'm not ready to try formatting and repairing the partition ([as this SU-er tried](https://superuser.com/a/863425/469529)), particularly as I'm unable to make a backup of it before doing so. Does anyone have a way around this, other than to switch to Macrium? ;)

The System Reserved partition resides in the first 100MB of my system disk - a Mushkin Chronos 120GB SSD. My C: takes up the remaining space and there are no other partitions on it. I'm not using BitLocker or BitDefender.

Comment: You should increase the size of the "System Reserved" partition to at least 300MB. The 100MB was an unfortunate decision by Microsoft, in retrospect.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I agree, but in order to increase the size I had to move my C: partition to make room - this moved the boot sector and broke the system until I moved it back again. Is there another way to change the size?

Comment: I am *fairly* sure I used [EaseUs Partition Manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm). I may have had to boot with the Windows 7 install disk and do a repair afterwards. I did have a drive image on a separate drive which I disconnected before starting the procedure, just in case, but I cannot remember what I used to create it.

Comment: Ah, I should have tried to repair it! I'll try again and see what happens.